# Generating function of trigonometric fuction

Tags: trigonometry, generating-functions

Find exponential generating function for following sequence:

$s_{n} = \sin{nt}$

the answer should be in terms of trigonometric functions. The exponential generating function is defined as:

$S(x)= \sum_{n\geq 0} s_{n} \frac{x^n}{n!} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine a function that simultaneously "generates" both $sin(nt)$ and $cos(nt)$. If you assume $x$ to be real, then you're looking for the imaginary part of the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in the following expression.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(cos(nt) + i.sin(nt)\right)\frac{x^n}{n!} \\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{int}\frac{x^n}{n!} \\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{n(ln(x) + it)}}{n!}
= e^{e^{ln(x) + it}} \\
= e^{x.e^{it}}
$$
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for replying. It looks make sense, but I cannot understand why you says "if you assume $x$ to be real, the you're looking for the imaginary part of the coefficient...". And how can I get the generating function of $S_{n} = \sin{nt}$ from this expression?

Comment: Another thing I doesn't understand is why  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{n(ln(x) + it)}}{n!}
= e^{e^{ln(x) + it}}$ ?

Comment: If $x$ and $t$ are real, then the generating function for $cos(nt)$ and $sin(nt)$ correspond to the real and imaginary parts of the final answer.
To answer your second question,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{n(ln(x) + it)}}{n!} \\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left[e^{ln(x)+it}\right]^n}{n!} \\
= e^\left[e^{ln(x)+it}\right]
$$

Comment: For the generating function you want, write out the final answer in the form $a + ib$, then $b$ will be the one you're looking for. 
$$
e^{x.e^{it}} = e^{x\left[cos(t) + i.sin(t)\right]} \\
e^{x.cos(t)}\left[cos(x.sin(t)) + i.sin(x.sin(t))\right]
$$
So your generating function would be $e^{x.cos(t)}sin(x.sin(t))$.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!